# My code is right but not accepted by Leetcode platoform. (ZigZag Conversion)

Tags: c++, string, c++14, std

It is a leet code [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/) under the subcategory of string, medium problem.

Query: My program is returning right result for all the test cases at the run time and but when I submit, same test cases are not passing.

I also made a video, [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mNPRTKKkgE&feature=youtu.be) to watch.

My Code is:

```
string convert(string s, int numRows) {
        
        int loc_rows = numRows-2;
        int i=0;
        int a=0,b=0;
        int arr[1000][1000];
        while(i<s.length())
        {
            if(a<numRows)
            {
                arr[a][b] = s[i];
                
                a++;
                i++;
            }
            else if(a>=numRows)
            {   
                if(loc_rows>=1)
                {
                    b++;
                    arr[loc_rows][b]=s[i];
                    i++;
                    loc_rows--;
                    
                }
                else{
                    loc_rows=numRows-2;
                    b++;
                    a=0;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        string result="";
        for(int d=0;d<numRows;d++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<b+1;y++)
            {
                char temp = (char)arr[d][y];
                if((temp>='a' and temp<='z') or (temp>='A' and temp<='Z')  )
                result+=temp;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        return result;
        
    }
```

Comment: Just a remark: your `arr` variable uses approx. 4 MB on the stack. Might be too much.

Comment: Either allocate for `arr` or make it a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @KlausGütter Okay, If you are right, what should I do here?  should I decrease my arr size? well, constraint is  **1 <= numRows <= 1000**

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). A question should be *self contained*, the problem statement and all requirements should be inside the question itself, not as links.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you mean I should go for dynamic array?

Comment: Allocate on the heap instead. Then you can also use the actually required size derived from s.length() and numRows.

Comment: @ChaudharySarimurrab `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(numRows, std::vector<int>(numRows));` --

Comment: If you know the actual input to your program, then you can do something which isn't taught by such sites: Debug your program. Using a debugger you can step through your program statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: @ChaudharySarimurrab Also, if you're sure your program is right, why not complain to LeetCode?  StackOverflow is not the LeetCode helpdesk.

Comment: If you have time constraints, then `int (*arr)[1000] = new int[1000][1000];` would be faster than a `std::vector<std::string>`, but `std::array<std::array>` would work as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes you are right David. But I am not getting TLE over there.  I am getting Wrong answer and only on submission not at the run time.

Comment: @ChaudharySarimurrab If the answer posted by code_fodder is correct, then if you had used `std::vector`, you would never had encountered the problem since the vector would have automatically set the elements to 0.

Comment: Remember, if you are using the rows in `arr` as a string (c-string) for output, they are NOT *nul-terminated* until you manually do it. If initializing the arrays is needed, then you can `memset (arr, 0, 1000*1000*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. @DavidC.Rankin PaulMcKenzie int arr[1000][1000] = {0}; This helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue might be your un-initialised arrays / variables.

Try setting initialising your array: `int arr[1000][1000] = {0};`

- live example failing: https://godbolt.org/z/dxf13P
- live example passing: https://godbolt.org/z/8vYEv6

You can't rely on the data that is in these arrays so initialising the values is quite important.

**Note:** this is because you rely on the empty values in the array to be not a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`). So that you can re-construct your output with your final loop which attempts to print the characters only. This works the first time around because luckily `arr` contains 0's in the gaps between your values (or at least not letters). The second time around it contains some junk from the first time around (really - you don't know what this is going to be, but in practise it is probably just the values you left in there from last time). So even though you put in the correct values into `arr` each time - your final loop finds some of the old `non-alpha` values in the `arr`ay - hence your program is incorrect...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we could also use unsigned int to make it just a bit more efficient:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

static const struct Solution {
    using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static const std::string convert(
        const std::string s,
        const int num_rows
    ) {
        if (num_rows == 1) {
            return s;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> res(num_rows);
        ValueType row = 0;
        ValueType direction = -1;

        for (ValueType index = 0; index < std::size(s); ++index) {
            if (!(index % (num_rows - 1))) {
                direction *= -1;
            }

            res[row].push_back(s[index]);
            row += direction;
        }

        std::string converted;

        for (const auto& str : res) {
            converted += str;
        }

        return converted;
    }
};
```